# iOS app installs due to Adwords campaign not attributed via Firebase

Tags: google-ads-api, firebase-analytics

I have both an iOS and Android app that have fully integrated the Firebase SDK:

- Android -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start
- iOS -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start

After setting up an Adwords campaign, and linking the Firebase environment and the Google Ad environment (refer to https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6383833?hl=en) only the first_open events are attributed to the campaign for Android, iOS is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by added `iad.framework` to the linked frameworks and libraries in the Xcode project. If you do not add this framework, the console logging from Firebase displays the following message:

[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.